# using row separator, column separator,split function,etc in javascript to show chat messages one below another

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, ajax, scripting

After using Ajax I get some chat messages returned in string form by webservice.
 Now I want to print that messages one below another. How may I use Column Separator(~) and row separator(@#) here.
This is how all messages returned are shown in a single line

```
User1 says :~Hello to this world and enjoy this week~sent at 05:40:30 AM@#User2 says :~Hello to my world~sent at 05:41:35 AM
```

some changes are required here to put the messages one below another

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function OnSuccess(data) {
       if (data.d)
       {
          div1.innerText = data.d;
       }
           }
  </script>
```

I wanted that two messages to look like this
[image]

Comment: are you referring about message seperation from sent to received ?

Comment: I have recived messages, but it is in a string and now I want to display it like the image

Comment: The simple way of doing it would be to split the whole string by row delimeter (@#) and store in a array, then for each value in array, split them by column delimeter(~) and place them in a associated array with `row => column`  value pairs, so that final step will be easy to parse this asocciated array and place respective content in respective location. i would suggest you to use a table for this chat window, as it will easy to place your text

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have to parse those strings, however if the parsing mechanism is not known you can use regex.

Comment: can I create a div using javascript and display it

Comment: yeah u can ...after u have parsed it,then dynamically add a div and embed the text to it

Answer (score 1):

```
var rows = data.d.split('@#');
for (var i in rows) {
  // Break the row into lines
  rows[i] = rows[i].split('~');
}
```

The **rows** variable is now a row / lines matrix you can use as you wish